# Azure Logic Apps - How to Disable Service Bus and Recurrence Triggers in VS Code when developing locally?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am developing a new Logic App in VS Code and created some workflows with Service Bus and Recurrence triggers.

When I run the project, I don't want some of these workflows to run and therefore require selectively disabling them.

Answer (score 3):

By adding below setting in local.settings.json file, you can disable logicapps.
**"Workflows.yourworkflowname.FlowState" : "Disabled"**

Have created a project in VS code and added two workflows as shown below,
[image]
[image]

Added configuration in local.settings.json file as shown below,
[image]

Once added both recurrence and service bus triggers are not running as shown below,
[image]

Note: Here recurrence trigger should run for every 10 sec. As it is in disabled state, recurrence trigger is not triggered.